# Is there a way to list channel in-use of RFCOMM in Linux?

Tags: linux, bluez, pybluez

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 running in vmplayer.

in PyBluez Example, rfcomm-server.py, Problem with running RFCOMM server on PORT_ANY

code chunk:

```
from bluetooth import *

erver_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)
```

I always get _bluetooth.error: (98, 'Address already in use') in the bind operation.

[This thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=521067) shows to disable pnat and it works. my questions are

1. In this case, how do I know which service is using the RFCOMM channel? is there command to list them?

   sdptool browse local

doesn't show that channel 1 is in use.

2. after disabling pnat in /etc/bluetooth/main.config, channel 1 seems released and I can run rfcomm-server.py without problem. However, even if I roll back by comment out the line "DisablePlugins = pnat" and restart bluetooth service again, channel 1 of RFCOMM is not occupied anymore!

Comment: The currently used channels can be read from `/sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/rfcomm`. The currently active RFCOMM sockets can be read from `/proc/net/rfcomm`. Unfortunately I cannot find any way to relate these entries, i.e. to get the channel used by a specific RFCOMM socket. The socket inode can be mapped to a process ID by searching for it in `/proc/*/fd/*`. It seems the kernel does not currently offer a netlink sock diag interface that could be used to gather this information.